# Can't grab the product name using selenium?

Tags: python, html, selenium, scrape

I am trying to grab this title as shown on a screenshot:
https://prnt.sc/C3eDuwhNTJhp

Tried by XPATH:

```py
name = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="product--page"]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div/h1/strong')

print(name.text)
```

It won't print anything out.

Tried by tagname:

```py
name = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'strong')
print(name.text)
```

Same result.

I tried this:

```py
name = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'strong')

for n in name:
    print(n.text)
```

It will give me the wanted name but it will also print the price (it is inside another strong tag in html.

Anyone can help?

Comment: Do you have any more specific attribute you can filter for? Otherwise, you will get all the `strong` tags

Comment: Can you add the full HTML of element?